# Can't set environment variable for debug node module

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) NPM module in conjuction with my express js app. However, when i try to create the environment variable and run the app, I do not receive any of the debug logs!

```
    var express = require("express");
var chalk = require("chalk");
var debug = require("debug")("app");

var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello from my library app! ");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    debug(`Listening on port ${chalk.green("3000")}. `);
});
```

I am running windows and am trying the following command in the terminal inside my project directory:
set DEBUG=* & node app.js

When i execute this command, the site works - but i do not get any logs atall!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried telling debug to use HTTP instead of app

`const debug = require('debug')('http');`

Express uses http in the back end and I assume it needs HTTP to be called

Edit: 
My mistake the (http) part is only namespace

To fix this I added

`debug.enabled = true;`

This seemed to fix it

Comment: Just tried this and i received the same output as before

Comment: I just updated my answer with the working solution. You can add that line any where after you require debug module